# Update list with ws

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub addJobs()
Dim rngJobs As Range
Dim c As Variant

Set rngJobs = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
MsgBox (rngJobs.Rows.Count)

For i = 1 To rngJobs.Rows.Count
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value ' renames the new worksheet

Next i


End Sub
```

I have a list of jobs and I want to be able to add a job number to that list and for vba to add that new job to my current list of worksheets. How do I do this? I'm unclear as to what is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub addJobs()
Dim rngJobs As Range, j
Dim c As Variant, sht As Worksheet

Set rngJobs = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
MsgBox (rngJobs.Rows.Count)

For i = 1 To rngJobs.Rows.Count

    j = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value

    Set sht = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if sheet not found
    Set sht = Sheets(j)
    On Error Goto 0      'stop ignoring any errors

    If sht Is Nothing Then 'sheet not already present: create it
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = j          'renames the new worksheet
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```